# In RTK-Query, Why 'isSuccess' (which is one of the properties of result a query) turns to 'true' before the fetching is over?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

There is a query made by RTK-query hook (useXXXQuery).
Let's say it is `useGetSomethingQuery`.

I am handling its result object with useEffect.

```
const res = useGetSomethingQuery(payload);

useEffect(() => {
  
  ...

  if (res.isSuccess) {
    // use the fetched Data
  }
},[res]);
```

As you can see, I am getting data from the server when `isSuccess` is set to `true`.

For the first time the API is called, the `isSuccess` turns to `true` after the status is set to `fulfilled` or `rejected`. In other words, after `isFetching` turns to `false`.

But the problem is, from the second time using the same api, `isSuccess` property turns to `true` even the fetching is not over. (its value is still `true`).

I think it is somewhat related to caching.. but have no idea about it.

Why `isSuccess` turns to `true` before it IS SUCCESSED?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not turn to true - it stays true.

After the first request for an endpoint/argument combination, you will have a value in the cache - and that value will either be a success or a failure. So no matter if there is currently data fetching, that data will stay available to you.

And if you are using the hook, it will go one step further. Imagine you go from page 5 to page 6. While page 6 is still fetching, you will still see the result for page 5 until page 6 is either a success or a failure - and for that long you will also see the success/error status for page 5.

Comment: thanks! then what is the most recommended way to differentiate each calls for the sake of making conditions? I'm currently detecting it with `isFetching` property

Comment: If you want something to go along with a call every time, it should probably be a lifecycle event on the endpoint definition, not something you track in the component. But if you are doing it, `isFetching` is probably fine.